# How do I block text walls/repeated text on discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py, bots

So I was wondering if there was anyway to delete text that has the same word over and over like MEE6 or YAGPDB.xyz I tried looking on google but couldn't find anything on google, if anyone knows how to do it I would really appreciate it if you could help me out

Comment: What have you attempted? (Hint, try using `on_message` and `wait_for`)

Comment: Are you looking for certain words or just any word that's repeating too much?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is missing a lot of information. Please look at ["how to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to improve your question. Add every information you have that might help us, but keep it as short as possible. If you have a question about code, please include the code. You can also take this short [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn more about Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to spot if a string contains only one word (repeated) here's a pretty simple way to achieve that

```py
if len(set(text.split())) == 1:
   # Text that only contains one type of word
```